# Store a value in variable from Postgres SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, variables

I have a variable from input:

```
$local1 = $_REQUEST['local1'];
```

I have tried this:

```
 $latitude1 = pg_query($db, "SELECT latitude FROM local_publico WHERE nome=$local1;");
 val1 = pg_fetch_result($latitude1, 0, 0);
```

Being that the query returns a a row with a single column.
However, whenever I try to use the variable `$val1`, it doesn't work, even a simple `echo()`.

New to SQL, I appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$local1 = $_REQUEST['local1'];
$latitude1 = pg_query($db, "SELECT latitude FROM local_publico WHERE nome=$local1;");
$val1 = pg_fetch_result($latitude1);
```

However, the above code is susceptible to SQL Injection. You should do something like this instead:

```
$local1 = $_REQUEST['local1'];
$result = pg_prepare($db, 'my_query', 'SELECT latitude FROM local_publico WHERE nome = $1');
$result = pg_execute($db, 'my_query', [$local1]);
$val1 = pg_fetch_result($result);
```

You can read more about SQL Injections [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).